# Emacs lisp char-table

Tags: emacs

I am a freshman with respect to learning emacs lisp and I'm therefore reading the emacs lisp manual. When i read [6.6 Char-Tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTables.html#Char_002dTables), I was confused about how to use the char-table. In that chapter, I can't find a good example to use char-table.

Of course, elisp has the syntax-table which consists of the char-table and syntax-table can do a lot of things.
I want to know how to make a good use of char-table and in which cases I would use it.

Thanks

Comment: If you think the Emacs doc needs to be improved, please make your (concrete) suggestion to the developers by using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Emacs Lisp programming, but alone from the description of the data structure I was immediately thinking of *keymaps*. And, as it turns out, [I was right](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Keymaps.html#Creating-Keymaps).

Especially the use of "parent" char-tables makes sense in this context: For example, when activating a mode, that mode probably has a keymap with the keybindings it provides. Before setting the current keymap to the mode's keymap, the current keymap is probably made the parent of the mode's keymap. That way, when the mode's keymap does not provide a mapping, the previous keymap(s) can be queried for an appropriate mapping.

---

Here's how I'd implement char-tables in C, as a rough sketch:

```c
struct char_table {
  void * data[256 /* or how many char codes there are */];
  struct char_table * parent;
};

void * lookup(
    struct char_table * table,
    char /* or a more suitable type for char codes */ key) {
  void * result = table.data[key /* plus possibly some calculation */];
  if (!result && table.parent) {
    result = lookup(table.parent, key);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: i don't know how it is mean,i am a c programmer,My comprehension is like that, char table is like below:   xxx['a']= object0 xxx['b']=object1 xxx['c']=object2

Comment: That's pretty much correct, except char-tables can be sparse, i.e. unused indices do not occupy any space (think hash / dict / associative array / Lisp assoc-list).

Answer (score 0):

Emacs's char-tables are simply a special kind of array that's indexed by *characters* rather than by *integers*.  There are many characters in Unicode, so it's worth having a special implementation of such an array where many ranges of characters share the same value.

Comment: "many ranges of characters share the same value".  Could you give an example? thanks